# Rails file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling to solve this error to upload file in rails
    Here's my code....I am a beginner, please help,, I have give below my Model, controllver,and view..The given below is my code

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.save(upload)

    name =  upload['upload'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['upload'].read) }
  end

  attr_accessible :category_id, :tutorial_date_release, :tutorial_discription, :tutorial_name, :tutorial_path, :tutorial_teacher_name, :tutorial_type, :upload  

  belongs_to :category

  validates_presence_of :category_id

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_date_release

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_discription

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_name

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_path

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_teacher_name

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_type

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_type

  #validates_presence_of :upload

  #validates_attachment_content_type upload, :content_type => 'application/pdf'

end
```

Here is my controller

```
class TutorialsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /tutorials
  # GET /tutorials.json
  def index
    @tutorials = Tutorial.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tutorials }
    end

  end
def uploadFile
    post = Tutorial.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
  # GET /tutorials/1
  # GET /tutorials/1.json
  def show
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tutorial }
    end
  end

  # GET /tutorials/new
  # GET /tutorials/new.json
  def new
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @tutorial }
    end
  end

  # GET /tutorials/1/edit
  def edit
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /tutorials
  # POST /tutorials.json
  def create
    @tutorial = Tutorial.new(params[:tutorial])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tutorial.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tutorial, notice: 'Tutorial was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @tutorial, status: :created, location: @tutorial }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @tutorial.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /tutorials/1
  # PUT /tutorials/1.json
  def update
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tutorial.update_attributes(params[:tutorial])
        format.html { redirect_to @tutorial, notice: 'Tutorial was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @tutorial.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tutorials/1
  # DELETE /tutorials/1.json
  def destroy
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
    @tutorial.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tutorials_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my VIew

```
<%= form_for(@tutorial) do |f| %>
  <% if @tutorial.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@tutorial.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this tutorial from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @tutorial.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tutorial_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tutorial_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_date_release %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :tutorial_date_release %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_teacher_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :tutorial_teacher_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_discription %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :tutorial_discription %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tutorial_path %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :tutorial_path %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :category_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :upload %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Whenever I submit I am having error like:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Users/Pritesh/Desktop/WebTutor-master/WebTutor-master

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/tutorials_controller.rb:50:in `block in create'
app/controllers/tutorials_controller.rb:49:in `create'
Request
```

Comment: why don't you try carrier-wave or papertrail gems. They provide pretty advance functionality.

Comment: I cant, I cant use any other gem ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your form should be set as multipart to be able to work with files:

`form_for(@tutorial, :html => { :multipart => true })`

2) Since your file upload field is inside the form, you need to access the value with:

`params[:tutorial][:upload]`

3) Check your stack trace and try to find where the call to the `name` method is happening as it seems that you are trying to call that method on a null object.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The other answers make good points; also, you shouldn't overwrite the Tutorial.save method, since the save method is defined by ActiveRecord in order to actually save your model inside the database; use a before_save or another callback instead

Answer (score 0):

Read about paperclip
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip
It's nice

If you want make your code working change `params` variable.
As is see

```
post = Tutorial.save(params[:upload])
```

should be

```
post = Tutorial.save(params[:tutorial])
```